# Phonegap hello world app could not launch in emulator through CLI

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, ant, android-emulator

I installed phonegap and created simple project(hello world). I installed jdk and sdk correctly. Paths are set. I want to launch my app in emulator. I run command "cordova run android" after a bunch of statements at the this results comes

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 14 seconds
Built the following apk(s):
    D:\phonegap\myapp\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator 'emulator-5554'.
Installing app on emulator...
Using apk: D:\phonegap\myapp\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS

But the app does not launches in emulator. I am using windows. I don't know what to do. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the work around. I installed the bluestack and it launched my app. when I run the command "cordova run android", after the build making process my app is automatically launched in blue stack. I don't know how but working.