# Trying to setup phonegap "Hello World!" project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

Guys i am following this [tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

but unfortunately, i am not able to configure it, I have stuck at this section:

**"Open a Project in the SDK"** .

After importing the project in Eclipse it shows 64 errors, most of them are related to packages like:

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The import org.apache.cordova.ConfigXmlParser cannot be resolved    WhitelistPlugin.java    /MainActivity/src/org/apache/cordova/whitelist  line 23 Java Problem`

**Edit:**

Ok, I have followed this link:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

and skipped "Open a New Project is SDK".

and directly execute these commands in "cmd":

`cordova build 
cordova build android 
cordova emulate android`

It shows in cmd:

`INSTALL SUCCESS
Unlocking Screen
Launching Application
LAUNCH SUCCESS`

but in simulator there is no application launched.

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: why use an outdated manual? here you have the current http://docs.phonegap.com/

Comment: @Del I have also tried this link after I installed phonegap desktop application ,successfully created new project, installed "Ripple Mission Control" google extension, after i put server path in chrome, phonegap's "Connecting Device" screen appears and page becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found the work around from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313741/phonegap-hello-world-app-could-not-launch-in-emulator-through-cli?rq=1)

I installed the "Blue Stak App Player" and after running this command:

`cordova run android`

It successfully installed and worked in "Blue Stack".

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

- First the doc your're following is for an old version, you should have a look at the newest version : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide
- Secondly, do you really want to open the project in eclipse? That's really not something needed unless you need to do some native dev in your app.
  You probably can ignore the "Open a Project in the SDK" section and just use the CLI to build and run your app.
- If you really want to use eclipse, I think you have this errors because you only imported your app but not the cordova libs. When you use the "Android project from existing code" wizard, make sure you select the platforms/android directory and then select all the projects, especially the CordovaLib project.
- And last but not least, you probably don't need phonegap and should use cordova instead. I don't know why phonegap is still refering to eclipse. Cordova now recommends using Android studio instead and maybe importing in eclipse doesn't work anymore with latest versions of cordova/phonegap? check cordova docs here : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide/platforms/android/index.html